# Gradle '+' dependencies (dynamic version) only finals?

Tags: gradle

I'm wondering if I can just use the final, non-beta subset of dependencies, when using dynamic versions, e.g.

```
 testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
```

downloads `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.12-beta-1/junit-4.12-beta-1.jar`, but I would like to use any final JUnit 4 version.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`version: 'latest.release'` gives the latest release version. There isn't currently a way to get the latest `4.` release version.